# Check a column for substring to assign new columns with values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

This is my dataframe with 2 columns:

```
ID      CODES
36233   LEH,PW
6175    N/A
6242    
6680    MS,XL,JFK
```

In column CODES, I need to identify the comma (",") and then count the number of commas and return it in a dataframe:

Output:

```
ID      CODES   HAS COMMA   NO. OF COMMAS
36233   LEH,PW  TRUE        1
6175    N/A     FALSE       0
6242            FALSE       0
6680  MS,XL,JFK TRUE        2
```

So far I've tried `DF['HAS COMMA'] = np.where(DF['CODE'].str.contains(','),True, False)` but this returns TRUE where there are blanks. :(

Additionally `DF['NO OF COMMAs']=DF['CODE'].count(",")` returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about with:

```
df['HAS COMMA'],df['NO. OF COMMA'] = [df.CODES.str.contains(',').fillna(False), df.CODES.str.count(',').fillna(0)]
```

prints:

```
      ID      CODES  HAS COMMA  NO. OF COMMA
0  36233     LEH,PW       True           1.0
1   6175        N/A      False           0.0
2   6242        NaN      False           0.0
3   6680  MS,XL,JFK       True           2.0
```